# How to send my GPS location (Latitude,Longitude) in a query string?

Tags: android, gps, query-string

I need to make a simple application for android that send the location of my smartphone every 25 seconds to a Web-app. My Web-app is online and right now i can pass the value manually like this:

> http://mywebapp.com/coordinates/create?latitude=18.463108&longitude=-69.929117

I'm an absolute beginner to Android development, so try to explain me step by step.

Comment: Avast tells your webpage is harmful :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing a deep research, I found what I think is the easiest way to send GPS location (Latitude,Longitude) in a query string. Maybe there's no shorter code in the web than this. So we'll do this in 2 steps:

1. First add this permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ```
2. Now the code in your `MainActivity.java` inside the class `public class MainActivity extends Activity { }`

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       public double latitude;
       public double longitude;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
           LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
           mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
       }

       /* Class My Location Listener */

       public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

           @Override
           public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
               latitude = loc.getLatitude();
               longitude = loc.getLongitude();
               String Text = "My current Latitude = " + latitude  + " Longitude = " + longitude;
               Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               SendQueryString(); // for send the  Query String of latitude and logintude to the webapp.
           }



           @Override
           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {   
               Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
           }


           @Override
           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
               Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }


           @Override
           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
           }

       }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */


       public void SendQueryString() {
           new Thread() {  
               public void run() {

                   String url = "http://mywebapp.com/coordinates/create?latitude=" + latitude +"&longitude=" + longitude;

                   try {
                       HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                       Client.execute(httpget);
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex) {
                       String fail = "Fail!";
                       Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),fail,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           }.start();
       }
   }
   ```

**NOTE:** As you can see I'm using `new Thread() { public void run() {/*code here*/}}.start();` in the function `SendQueryString()`, that's because we're trying to make a request to a server, so in Android you can't make a request to a server in the principal Thread, where the graphics and principal process are. In fact it'll return an error if you try to make a request in the principal Thread.

Answer (score 0):

First get location:

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locMan.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, location listener);
```

The first zero represents the time interval of the location updating
The second one represents the distance interval of the updating .. configure as you will.

And in the listener:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
if (location != null) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double long = location.getLongitude();
   }
}
```

You just have to a make an http request with that link like the following:

```
String url = "http://mywebapp.com/coordinates/createlatitude=" + lat +"&longitude=" + long;
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: Obtaining location in such brute way is not a good practice. Even GPS provider can send location updates in non-predictable order, I mean it can send location with 10m accuracy and after a second with 50m accuracy. Some kind of additional check when receiving locations real-time is needed.

Comment: A very valid point .. those snippets are only to show the concepts and are not to be used exactly that way.
The accuracy of time and distance can be changed to his configurations

Comment: and of cource it is a better practice to subscribe to both Network and GPS providers to follow cases in which gps is unavailable or disabled by user.

Comment: Ok Mahmoud I will try it, and if it work i will give you the points.

Comment: Mahmoud Elmorabea i was trying to test your code, but there are a lot of error in the code, please try it yourself and then copy again.